# .htaccess redirect within WordPress Multi-site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Using a standard WordPress setup I had the following in htaccess...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^registration=disabled$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php$ http://www.mysite.com/register [L,R=301,NC]
```

Which successfully redirected any calls to wp-login.php?registreation=disabled to http://www.mysite.com/register

I have now moved over to multi-site so need the redirect to send the user to whatever site within the network they are browsing, how can i do this?

UPDATE

To clarify, as I am now using multi-site I could now be faced with different sub-domains and addresses such as

www.mydomain1.com/testsite
www.mydomain2.com/example
www.mydomain3.com/various

I am looking for a one size fits all htaccess command that will redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the domain from your `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^registration=disabled$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php$ /register [L,R=301,NC]
```

Tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it seems to work, although it doesn't trim off the query string (but then, neither does the original).  If you want the query string removed, make the `RewriteRule` the following:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php$ /register? [L,R=301,NC]
```

---

**Edit:** I can't test this on a real system at the moment, and unfortunately the link I provided doesn't support `${HTTP_HOST}`, however you could add another condition which matches *any* http_host, and use a back-reference in the RewriteRule to put in that value:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^registration=disabled$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteRule ^wp-login.php$ http://%1/register? [L,R=301,NC]
```

As mentioned, I can't currently test this, but in theory it should work :)

Comment: Not sure that works in my situation as it just redirects to the main multi-site account and not the site the request has come from.  i have updated the questions..